# Django can't save comment to post properly

Tags: python, django, forms, captcha

i want to save a comment for my post but for some reasone the view returns (if i enter a wrong captcha):

> The view MyProject.views.comment_new didn't return an HttpResponse
>   object. It returned None instead.

Any idea what could be the reason for this behaviour?
Sadly this is the only place/form where it seems that my captcha simply get ignored

template.html:

forms.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, it will return the error:

> Didn't return an HttpResponse object

Because if your `form.is_valid()` returns `False` there is no execution path to continue on, and thus `None` is returned.

You would need to do this:

```
def comment_new(request, pk):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = CommentForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
            comment = form.save(commit=False)
            comment.author = request.user
            comment.published_date = timezone.now()
            comment.post = post
            comment.save()
            return redirect('post_detail', pk=comment.post.pk)
        else: # If for is NOT valid:
            form = CommentForm(request.POST)
            return render(request, 'MyProject/comment_new.html', {'form': form})
    else:
        form = CommentForm()
        return render(request, 'MyProject/comment_new.html', {'form': form})
```

Or to keep your code from visually repeating (keep thing "DRY"):

```
def comment_new(request, pk):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = CommentForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
            comment = form.save(commit=False)
            comment.author = request.user
            comment.published_date = timezone.now()
            comment.post = post
            comment.save()
            return redirect('post_detail', pk=comment.post.pk)
    else:
        form = CommentForm()

    # Note the indentation (this code will be executed both if NOT POST
    # and if form is not valid.
    return render(request, 'MyProject/comment_new.html', {'form': form})
```

Answer (score 1):

This line

```
if form.is_valid():
```

should have an `else` branch or else it will return `None`